Looking for a web page listing possible destinations
I copied a web listing of locations that one might travel to.  There were more than a thousand, and either they were numbered or I added line numbers.  But I have gaps in the numbers, and wanted to find the page again.  However, web searches for some of the strings turned up nothing.  Anyone able to cite the URI?
Here are two of the places:
Slovenia - Western (Ljubljana, Bled, Kranj, Koper, Piran) / #60
Mexico - Mexico State (Toluca) and Morelos (Cuernavaca) / #1319
Since @Doc found the site, and I looked at it, it clearly is travel-related and others might also be interested.

I’m voting to close this question because this isn't Google.  Also, Google finds https://nomadmania.com/ which is probably what you're after

There are better alternatives than NSA's largest competitor hence "web search" instead of the name.  But looking at that site, it does contain both of the strings my web search did not find.  Perhaps in this case, the G-word would have been better.  :-)

So your "better alternatives" didn't find the site, but Google did?  And that hasn't left you questioning whether the "alternatives" really are "better" or not?

Better, because (1) they don't save information to profile you; (2) they don't use such information to give ytou results to reinforce your biases; and (3) they don't sell positions at the top of their results.

@doc, +1 for finding what is probably the correct site.  Not for the close vote.  Now that I've seen it again, it obviously IS a travel-related site that other travelers might like to know about.

Stack Exchange sites, in my experience, typically discourage answers which are just links to other sites, because answers are expected to be self-contained so that they don't suffer from link-rot when those other sites change or disappear. IMO your question is off-topic because you're specifically looking for that kind of answer.

Maybe.  On the other hand, I would think travel enthusiasts would welcome knowing about such sites, but copying the entire content here would be inappropriate.
